# I want to crawl all the posts on medium.com site

Tags: medium.com-publishing-api

I want to crawl all the posts on medium.com site.

The problem is that all posts on the medium.com site are not available for information.

There are also often media sites where site url changes.
I don't know how to solve this problem.

I was not good at English so I turned the translator around.
I'm sorry.

I visited the medium developer page and looked at the api code.

But I couldn't figure out how to get all the information on all the boards I wanted to bring.

Are all user information or all bulletin board information available?

Finally, if the above is available, the croller will be able to find the information he or she wants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like their API allows you to see anything other than whatever account you're logged into is subscribed to or has access to write/edit.  I assume that's the issue you're running into:

"Returns a full list of publications that the user is related to in some way: This includes all publications the user is subscribed to, writes to, or edits. This endpoint offers a set of data similar to what you’ll see at https://medium.com/me/publications when logged in."

https://github.com/Medium/medium-api-docs#32-publications

Answer (score 2):

Unfortuanality, the medium doesn't provide all the post's details. Medium provides only the last 10 posts [RSS feeds](https://help.medium.com/hc/en-us/articles/214874118-RSS-feeds) there for you need to convert those into JSON objects. use the below link and replace your user name instead of @userName. In Medium API you could get publications posts but you couldn't get the user's post. Read the [docs](https://github.com/Medium/medium-api-docs).

https://api.rss2json.com/v1/api.json?rss_url=https://medium.com/feed/@userName